# What does Float* mean?

Tags: c#, opencv, c#-4.0

I'm trying to understand how a code functions and couldn't understand a very important part because of this part. could you please explain what does float* means and how it differs when we use *x than x?

Why the value of f1 anf f2 changes after each iteration? is it because of IplImages[0] and IplImages[1] .toPointer? please explain.

```
List<IplImage> IplImages;

float* f1 = (float*)IplImages[0].ImageData.ToPointer();
float* f2 = (float*)IplImages[1].ImageData.ToPointer();
.
.
.
.
if (*(f2 + row * imageWidth) > m)
 {
   m = *(f2 + row * imageWidth);
   .....
 }
```

Comment: could you please explain more? for example here the value of f2 at the begining is 27225 but at *(f2 + row * imageWidth) its 100 . why and how?

Comment: [Related:Unsafe code in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3173008/332733)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C#, any data type in parenthesis represents a cast. In this case, it is casting to a float pointer. The `*` in C# represents a pointer type. Pointers are special data types that "point" to an area in memory where the data is being held. Think of it as manipulating addresses. In your code here:

```
if (*(f2 + row * imageWidth) > m)
```

The code is being used as a dereferencing pointer. What this is saying, in English, is "Take the address pointed to by `f2` and add to it the product of `row` and `imageWidth`, then dereference (dereference just means to return the data stored at by `f2` plus the product of `row` and `imageWidth`) and see if its greater than `m`. Here is a visual:

```
                       -------------------------------------------
Memory Location -->    | 1000 | 1001 | 1002 | 1003 | 1004 | 1005 |
                       -------------------------------------------
            Data -->   |  86  |  130 | 190  |  221 |  12  | 99   |
                       -------------------------------------------
```

If `f2` equals `1000`, then `*f2` would return `86`. `*(f2 + 1)` would return `130`. Now in my example, I am assuming `float` takes up one byte of storage data. It doesn't though. In the CLR, `float` takes up 4 bytes (You can see this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx)). So `(f2 + 1)` would actually equal 1004 and would actually return `12`. This is called pointer arithmetic. The arithmetic might vary among different processors. If a float is 8 bytes long, then `(f2 + 1)` would equal `1008`.

Because C#'s automatic garbage collector sometimes wants to relocate stuff on the heap, and because pointers can manipulate data that normally couldn't be manipulated, pointers are unsafe in C# and must be wrapped in an `unsafe` block to use.

Comment: That was so clear. thanks. so basically the value that is shown beside f1 and f2 has nothing to do with the value of the whole parentheses (as you said it is just the address of it)?

Comment: @user3907694 - Correct. It holds an address. To get the value stored at the address, you must dereference it (e.g. `*(f2)`)

Comment: And what do IplImages[0] and IplImages[1] represent? (the code is working with the video frames and performs some task on it)

Comment: @user3907694 - Those are arrays. `lplImages[0]` pulls the first element of the array. `lplImages[1]` pulls the second element of the array.

Comment: it would be great if you also translate this line of the code "float* f1 = (float*)IplImages[0].ImageData.ToPointer();" to english please ;)  Does each IplImages[ ] mean a frame of the video that I think not because the code performs this task on each frame separately?

Comment: Well its hard to know exactly without seeing all the code, but it looks like you have a collection of images, stored in an array called `IplImages`. `IplImages[0]` is accessing the first image in your collection. The `.ImageData` looks to be a property that returns the raw data of that image. `.ToPointer()` returns an address to that raw data. The `(float *)` converts that address into a pointer. `f1` now contains the address of that image data.

Answer (score 1):

`float*` refers to a pointer which can only be used in an [`unsafe` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx). A pointer is exactly that, a pointer to a place in memory. The reason for using them is often performance, although in many cases the same result can be achieved without too much performance degradation in safe code.